# Swift how to center and vertical label's text

Tags: ios

I had a problem about label of cell in my table view, the text is not in the center of cell.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", 
    for: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell

    cell.labelLeft.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    cell.labelRight.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    cell.labelLeft.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
    cell.labelRight.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters

    cell.labelLeft.attributedText = labelTwoArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.labelRight.text = labelFourArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.99, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.88, green:0.91, blue:0.91, alpha:1.0).cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

    return cell
}
```

I tried the methods that other guys suggested before in the Internet, but they did not work.

Here is my app's table view image:

[image]

I did not change the setting of storyboard, the labelLeft Line Break Model is "Clip", the labelRight Line Break Model is "Truncate Tail".

Does anyone know the reason of this problem?

Comment: Do you use autolayout for the cell? Maybe constraint failure will result in these type of issues

Comment: @arunjos007 Yes,you are right, looks like here is the problem.But I do not know the reason, I just used bottom ,left ,top constraints 0-0-0, but I think I need it for layout.

Comment: @ Puneet Sharma I do not know why change the labels' position will helps , it just not in the center?

Comment: It may be related to the top constraint. Please try with different constraint constants. Also, check it is connected to contentView of cell

Comment: @arunjos007 Ok,I will try some different set of constraint ,thanks for your help.

Comment: If you set a background color on your labels, you will likely see that they are aligned to the TOP of the cell. Try setting the "center vertically" constraint instead.

Comment: @AlenLee: I am sorry, I was looking at the problem in a wrong way. Instead of aligning labels to top and bottom, align it vertically to center.

Comment: @Puneet Sharma Yeah,I will try it ,looks like autolayout is a difficult tech.Thanks for help.

Comment: @DonMag Yeah, here is the problem ,I got wrong with setting cell in some way,I will try to your method, thanks.